# ES6 modules, babel/webpack. Import/Export statements not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Ok so am learning react, es6 and webpack/babel. I got my webpack.config set up below:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const parts = require('./config/webpack-parts');

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: PATHS.app + '/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

const common = {
    entry: {
        app: PATHS.app

    },

    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: '[name].js'

    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]

};

var config;

switch(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event) {
    case 'build':
        config = merge(
            common,
            {
                devtool: 'source-map',
                output: {
                    path: PATHS.build,
                    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
                    // This is used for require.ensure. The setup
                    // will work without but this is useful to set.
                    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
                }
            },
            parts.clean(PATHS.build),
            parts.extractBundle({
                name: 'vendor',
                entries: ['react']
            }),

            parts.minify(),
            parts.extractCSS(PATHS.app)
        );
        break;
    default:
        config = merge(
            common,
            parts.setupCSS(PATHS.app),
            {
                devtool: 'eval-source-map'
            },
            parts.devServer({
                // Customize host/port here if needed
                host: process.env.HOST,
                port: process.env.PORT
            })
        );
        break;
}

module.exports = validate(config);
```

The 'config/webpack-parts' file is just some extra modules/plugins and not needed for the question. Was just aiming to make this reusable across projects. I got babel set up also, and the .babelrc file is below

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

I have also got all the nesscary babel/webpack plugins installed inside my package.json file:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.10",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "uglify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack-validator": "^2.2.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
  }
```

So now the problem. I am testing out that this all works and converts es6+react code into es5 using babel etc. I have set up test 'hello.js' and 'world.js' files and I am importing them into my entry/main file 'index.js'. This is where the error is.

hello.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Hello extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

world.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class World extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>World</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from 'hello';
import World from 'world';

ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
ReactDOM.render(<World/>, document.getElementById('world'));
```

Pre web pack index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <div id="world"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error on web pack when I run web pack to do its thing.

```
ERROR in ./app/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'hello' in /Users/Foysal/Google Drive/Learning Projects/ReactJS-Tutorial/weather-app/app
 @ ./app/index.js 11:13-29
```

I get a similar error for the 'world.js' file and i have no clue what is wrong with the import/export statements. I am just new to es6 modules but I have exported and imported correctly as far as I am aware. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: where do these files exist in relation to index?

Comment: I checked the correct answer below. It was to do with where the files were in relation to the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use relative path, when you are requiring files, for example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from '../components/hello';
import World from '../components/world';
```

In your example, node looking for `hello` and `world` modules in `node_modules` directory.

Comment: how can you tell that? and yea that was the problem. I have hello.js, world.js, index.html and index.js all inside the same folder, so why does it not by default look in the same directory? Is it the way modules work in es6? Thanks

Comment: @Foysal94, yes, by default, if not to point path, module will be searched in `node_modules` dir. You always should provide path when you are requiring files. If all files are in the same directory, use `import Hello from './hello'`;